# Shortcut control enter does not work in R script

Tags: r, rstudio

ctrl+R no longer works for executing script lines.

This is not a hardware/keyboard problem.

I have also restarted my PC.

I have tried on a different PC.

I have recently switched from using R to using RStudio. I thought this may have something to do with it, so I opened and resaved the script in RStudio, to no effect.

Furthermore, I have created an R-Project folder and have copied the files, including the script in question, into it. Then I started R-Studio and opened the project.

I would like to post my sessionInfo(), but do not know how to do that without executing the command.

Keep in mind that I only use R for stats purposes. I don't know much about informatics or other types of programming etc., so please try to keep it simple for me. Thanks!

Comment: If you press `ALT+SHIFT+K` you should see all the shortcuts of r-studio, maybe the problem is a misconfiguration.

Comment: I checked that alreadz, that is also not the problem. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the script file (for some reason unkown to me) did not have the correct extension (.R). When I added that to the script file extension, it worked fine again.

Answer (score 17):

In addition to the solution offered above, in Rstudio, `Ctrl + Enter` does not work if the chunk is broken in `.Rmd` files.

For example, if you press `CTRL + Enter` on the following line (`2+2`), it won't work:

````
```{r}
2+2
``
````

The chunk should end three Backtick characters, not two.

Comment: This is often very difficult to spot.